# this.id is not working to detect which link is clicked in href

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am creating a bookstore using the google API. I have a small issue which I couldn't figure out. In the below piece of code that I saw  from example code of google api bookstore  function, I am trying to create href for the title of the book and pass its selfLink to the destination page i.e book-description.html.

When I put alert(this.id) on onclick It works, but for a normal method get(this) it does not work. I do not need an alertbox I want to take the id of the link clicked in href and pass it to another html.

```js
handleResponse(response) {
  for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
    var item = response.items[i];
    var a = item.volumeInfo.title;
    var selfL = item.selfLink;
    //var b = a.link("book-description.html");
    var image = item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "</br>" + "</br>" + "<br>" + "<img src =" + "'" + image + "'" + " class='im'/>";
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<h4 class='right'>" + "<a href = 'book-description.html'id = " + "'" + selfL + "'" + 
      "onclick ='get(this);'>" + a + "</a></h4>";

    function get(e) {
      var link = e.id;
      localStorage.setItem("Link", link);
    }
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<h4 class='right'>" + "AUTHOR:" + item.volumeInfo.authors + "</h4>";
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<h5 class='right'>" + "PUBLISHER:" + item.volumeInfo.publisher + "</h5>";
    var rating = item.volumeInfo.averageRating;
    if (rating) {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<h5 class='right' id='rating'>" + rating + "</h5>";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<h5 class = 'right' id ='rating'>Not Rated Yet</h5>";
    }
    //document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + "<br>" + "<br>"  + item.volumeInfo.publisheddate;

  }
}
```

Comment: how is this [tag:jquery] related, when all I see is good ol' vanilla js?

Comment: Where is the code that tries to read the value from `localStorage`? Maybe that's where the problem is. (Also, why are you defining `function get()` inside your for loop?)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help], create a [mcve] with enough HTML to see how you assign the handler

Comment: @mplungjan while your comment is apt, that is there (`"onclick ='get(this);'>"`)

Comment: I did not scroll to see that - I reformatted to show it now. Anyway - we need a JSON file in  a snippet - but now I notice the scope.

Comment: Where is your get method ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems with your code, but specifically in answer to  your question; your function `get` is scoped so it is only available within the function `handleResponse`. For it to be accessible from an `onclick` it must be in page scope.

Simply move this

```
function get(e) {
  var link = e.id;
  localStorage.setItem("Link", link);
}
```

Into the head of your page

---

In programming there is the concept of DRY (Don't repeat yourself). So store a reference to `document.getElementById("content")` and reuse that variable.

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
content.innerHTML = ...
```

---

You're missing some spaces in your output html. This may work in some browsers, others will struggle

```
<a href = 'book-description.html'id=
```

Should have a space between the end of one attribute and the start of another

```
<a href='book-description.html' id=
```

---

And for heaven sake, sort out the concatenation of your strings. You dont need a `+` if its just a simple string

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "</br>" + "</br>";
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "</br></br>";
```

Comment: And save the reference to content

Comment: @mplungjan - not sure what that comment meant? Was it for me or the OP?

Comment: Both :) It is a good idea to have only one `var content = document.getElementById("content")` as I am sure you know

Comment: Ah, now I get it. You're saying DRY!